# Local variable resetting to 0

Tags: c, pointers, variables, local-variables

I'm writing a simple registration code. I ask the user to type a menu option, through the input_menu function. Until then the variable n works. However, in the next step, the variable is already set to 0, ignoring user input via scanf. What's happening? I'm also open to suggestions for improving the code. Thank you very much in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Aluno {
    char nome[51];
    char data_de_nascimento[11];
    char cpf[15];
    char rg[13];
    char email[255];
    long int matricula;
    bool valido = false;
};

void imprimir_menu() {
    printf("CADASTRO DE ALUNOS\n\n");
    printf("[1] NOVO CADASTRO\n");
    printf("[2] EDITAR CADASTRO\n");
    printf("[3] LISTAR CADASTROS\n");
    printf("[0] SAIR\n\n");
}

void input_menu(int n) {
    for (;;) {
        system("cls");
        imprimir_menu();
        scanf("%d", &n); // consider e.g. n == 3
        if (n >= 0 && n <= 3) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("\nOPCAO INVALIDA. INSIRA UMA DAS OPCOES DO MENU.\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    printf("%d", n); // n will be 3, that's correct
}

void listar_cadastros(Aluno alunos[], int x) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (alunos[i].valido == true) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (i == x - 1 && flag == 0) {
            printf("NAO EXISTE NENHUM ALUNO CADASTRADO.");
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}

void input_decisao(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {

    } else if (n == 2) {

    } else if (n == 3) {
        printf("teste");
        //listar_cadastros(alunos, x);
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int x = 2;
    Aluno cadastro_alunos[x];
    for (;;) {
        input_menu(n);
        printf("%d", n); // n == 0 (??)
        input_decisao(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: `input_menu()` should return the value entered by the user. Or you can pass `n` as a pointer. `n` is passed by value (a copy) so the `n` in main is not modified by `input_menu()`.

Comment: `n` inside `input_menu` is a copy of the variable in `main` so whatever you do to it in that function won't change the original. You could pass a pointer the the variable in `main` and change it inside `input_menu`, but returning a value is a better and more clear choice.

Comment: It worked! I was thinking that I would modify the original. Thank you for your help.